# Xcode - Most Streamlined way of saving a lot of integers to a file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsmutabledictionary, nskeyedarchiver

i am currently saving 30 integers to a file by creating a NSMutableDictionary and then using the NSKeyedArchiver to save it.

```
@interface:
NSInteger highScoreE;
NSInteger highScoreM;
NSInteger highScoreH;
NSInteger highScoreI;

NSInteger highScoreComE;
NSInteger highScoreComM;
NSInteger highScoreComH;
NSInteger highScoreComI;

NSInteger totalGamesWonE;
NSInteger totalGamesWonM;
NSInteger totalGamesWonH;
NSInteger totalGamesWonI;

NSInteger totalGamesLostE;
NSInteger totalGamesLostM;
NSInteger totalGamesLostH;
NSInteger totalGamesLostI;

NSInteger totalPointsForE;
NSInteger totalPointsForM;
NSInteger totalPointsForH;
NSInteger totalPointsForI;

NSInteger totalPointsAgainstE;
NSInteger totalPointsAgainstM;
NSInteger totalPointsAgainstH;
NSInteger totalPointsAgainstI;

NSInteger highScore;
NSInteger highScoreCom;
NSInteger totalGames;
NSInteger totalGamesWon;
NSInteger totalGamesLost;
NSInteger totalPointsFor;
NSInteger totalPointsAgainst;

@property(nonatomic) NSInteger highScoreE;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger highScoreM;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger highScoreH;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger highScoreI;

@property(nonatomic) NSInteger highScoreComE;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger highScoreComM;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger highScoreComH;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger highScoreComI;

@property(nonatomic) NSInteger totalGamesWonE;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger totalGamesWonM;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger totalGamesWonH;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger totalGamesWonI;

@property(nonatomic) NSInteger totalGamesLostE;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger totalGamesLostM;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger totalGamesLostH;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger totalGamesLostI;

@property(nonatomic) NSInteger totalPointsForE;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger totalPointsForM;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger totalPointsForH;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger totalPointsForI;

@property(nonatomic) NSInteger totalPointsAgainstE;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger totalPointsAgainstM;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger totalPointsAgainstH;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger totalPointsAgainstI;

@property(nonatomic) NSInteger highScore;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger highScoreCom;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger totalGames;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger totalGamesWon;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger totalGamesLost;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger totalPointsFor;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger totalPointsAgainst;


@implementation;

NSString *nssTotalPointsFor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", totalPointsFor];
NSString *nssTotalPointsForE = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", totalPointsForE];
NSString *nssTotalPointsForM = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", totalPointsForM];
NSString *nssTotalPointsForH = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", totalPointsForH];
NSString *nssTotalPointsForI = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", totalPointsForI];
//create dictionary
NSMutableDictionary* myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

//add things to dictionary (game stats)
[myDict setObject:nssTotalPointsFor forKey:@"totalPointsFor"];
[myDict setObject:nssTotalPointsForE forKey:@"totalPointsForE"];
[myDict setObject:nssTotalPointsForM forKey:@"totalPointsForM"];
[myDict setObject:nssTotalPointsForH forKey:@"totalPointsForH"];
[myDict setObject:nssTotalPointsForI forKey:@"totalPointsForI"];

//get the path
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"stats.save"];

// save to file
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:myDict toFile:path];
```

and then i do this similarly for the other integers.

Then I have to read these strings back into the integers:

```
//get the path
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"stats.save"];   

//create dictionary
NSMutableDictionary* myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

//read from file
myDict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
NSString *nssPlayerHighScore = [myDict objectForKey:@"playerHighScore"];
highScore = [nssPlayerHighScore intValue];

NSString *nssComputerHighScore = [myDict objectForKey:@"computerHighScore"];
highScoreCom = [nssComputerHighScore intValue];

NSString *nssTotalPointsFor = [myDict objectForKey:@"totalPointsFor"];
totalPointsFor = [nssTotalPointsFor intValue];

NSString *nssTotalPointsAgainst = [myDict objectForKey:@"totalPointsAgainst"];
totalPointsAgainst = [nssTotalPointsAgainst intValue];

NSString *nssTotalGames = [myDict objectForKey:@"totalGames"];
totalGames = [nssTotalGames intValue];

NSString *nssTotalGamesWon = [myDict objectForKey:@"totalGamesWon"];
totalGamesWon = [nssTotalGamesWon intValue];

NSString *nssTotalGamesLost = [myDict objectForKey:@"totalGamesLost"];
totalGamesLost = [nssTotalGamesLost intValue];

NSString *nssPlayerHighScoreE = [myDict objectForKey:@"playerHighScoreE"];
 highScoreE = [nssPlayerHighScoreE intValue];

NSString *nssComputerHighScoreE = [myDict objectForKey:@"computerHighScoreE"];
highScoreComE = [nssComputerHighScoreE intValue];
```

and then so on for the other integers as well.

I find this way extremely cumbersome and annoying but I don't know any other ways to save integers.

What is the most streamlined way of saving things in general?

I don't know if NSKeyedArchiver is the problem or should I be making the strings contain more than one integer (eg.NSString *nssTotalPointsFor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i, %i, ...", totalPointsFor, totalPointsAgainst, ...];.

But then how would I change the numbers in the string back into the integers?

Or do I use an array somehow?

Give me your I idea and I am open to many suggestions.

Thx a lot I don't know much about programing.

Comment: Just a thought, if you want to trim down the total line count on your code, you can declare your integers like this. "NSInteger one, two, three, four, five;"

Answer (score 3):

Storing these numbers into "`NSString`" objects and archiving them with that big block of code does indeed seem really cumbersome.

Why not do this with ["`NSNumber`" objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/initWithInt%3a), which have archiving capability built in?  You could throw all those "`NSNumber`" objects into an array (e.g. "`highScoreENumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: highScoreE];`") and write it to a file and then load up the file on subsequent launches.

EDIT:

I can't port of your code for you, but check this out:

```
@interface:
{
    NSNumber * highScore;
    NSNumber * highScoreCom;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * highScore;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * highScoreCom;

@implementation;

//create dictionary
NSMutableDictionary* myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

if(myDict)
{
    //add things to dictionary (game stats)
    [myDict setObject:highScore forKey:@"highScore"];
    [myDict setObject:highScoreCom forKey:@"highScoreCom"];

    //get the path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"stats.save"];

    BOOL successfulWrite = [myDict writeToFile: path atomically: YES];
    if(successfulWrite == NO)
    {
        NSLog( @"could not write my file to path %@", path );
    }
    // if *not* using ARC, don't forget to release
    [myDict release];
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't think I understand how to do that. Much appreciated though.

Comment: Oh ok thx. But everytime it loads would it call the integers from the file? I don't know how to do that :(

Comment: When it loads the dictionary from the saved file, you can get at the integers via stuff like "`NSNumber * highScore = [myDict objectForKey: @"highScore"]; NSLog( @"high score is %d", [highScore intValue] );`".  Look at how you can set and get the integers in and out of "`NSNumber`" objects.  It's really easy once you get accustomed to it.